# Отображение объектов на карте из geoJSON (пример из Песочницы)

Tags: yandex-maps-api, geojson

Изучаю примеры с Песочницы и возник вопрос:
экспортирую файлы из примера "Добавление на карту GeoJSON файла" и затем открываю html-файл с компьютера. Карта загружается, но на ней отсутствуют метки.
При экспорте на jsfiddle все ок.
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager_geojson

Я абсолютный новичок, пыталась найти проблему сама, но безрезультатно.
Буду благодарна, если кто-нибудь даст объяснение.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если открыть консоль браузера, то можно увидеть причину этого. Там написано

> Failed to load file:///.../geoObjects.geojson: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

То есть для того чтобы использовать это локально, нужно поднять веб сервер. 
К примеру можно воспользоваться программой WebStorm для открытия этого примера в браузере.

Comment: Почитала про ошибку, у chrome идет блокировка локальных файлов при запуске, поэтому пока использую firefox, там блокировки нет. Потом дойду до веб сервера. Спасибо, что толкнули в правильное направление!

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно получить API ключ Яндекс. В самом html файле есть комментарий:

```
<!--
   Укажите свой API-ключ. Тестовый ключ НЕ БУДЕТ работать на других сайтах.
   Получить ключ можно в Кабинете разработчика: https://developer.tech.yandex.ru/keys/
-->
```

И подставить его сюда:
https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&coordorder=longlat&apikey=**<ваш API-ключ>**

Comment: Добавляла. Ключ новый, кол-во запросов минимальное. Все равно ничего не отражается :( Думала, что это из-за того, что данные хранятся  отдельно в локальном файле, но по идее это не должно влиять